# how can I initialize the second click by the first click jquery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code is very simple, look below. I want whenever a user click the first div, it will initialized the second click, which it consider the user click both div. I had to do this way, so can I achieve that? Thanks.

```js
   
 $('#first_div').on( "click", function(){
   alert('first');
});

$('#no_need_click').on('click',function(){
    alert('successfully');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='first_div'>first_div</div>
<div id='no_need_click'>no_need_click</div>
```

Comment: can you better explain your problem

Comment: So you mean whenever they click on `#first_div` you want to setup the event for `#no_need_click`, or do you mean when they click on `#first_div` it will also trigger a click on `#no_need_click`?

Comment: `$("#no_need_click").click();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to click no_need_click when first_div clicked, if so then you can do this

```
$('#first_div').on( "click", function(){
         alert('first');
         $('#no_need_click').trigger('click');
});
```